# How to hide labels on small screen?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, antd

I have antd menu with labels and icon.
Here is the minimal representation of design.
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-5vkhf6?file=/index.js)

Now what I want is to hide the labels and show only icons when menu is starting to show ellipsis. As I am not so fluent with CSS, I wonder if this can be done by means of antd.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use media queries and set display none your labels below a certain size.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    span.ant-menu-title-content {
    display: none;
    }
}
```

I would personnaly advice you to take this one above ( It's the most common one used for the swap between desktop & mobile)

Last thing think about center your menu items on mobile with a justify-content: center :)

Comment: Looks like a surgery, but if this is how it's done then I will go with it. Thanks also for the tip. I just thought there is a way like many antd components have specifiers for different sizes.

Comment: Although it works, but not at the time when ellipses are appearing in nav bar as I mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 991px) {
   .ant-layout-header .ant-menu-item .ant-menu-title-content{
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Take a parent class above the menu so that this css doesn't appear on any other page

Answer (score 0):

In my antd project I use `useBreakpoints` to determine my screen size:

```
import {Grid} from 'antd'

function Index() {
  const { useBreakpoint } = Grid
  const breakpoints = useBreakpoint()

  // now you can handle this anyway you want, here is how I've done in my project:
  const [isWidescreen, setIsWidescreen] = useState(true)

  useEffect( () => {
    setIsWidescreen( () => !( breakpoints.xs || (
      breakpoints.sm && !breakpoints.xl
    ) ) )
  }, [ breakpoints ] )

  return (<>
    <Menu
      // ... all other props
      mode="inline"
      inlineCollapsed={ !isWidescreen }
    />
  </>)
}
```

You can also create a context or a custom hook to use this anywhere you want.

You can also find all breakpoints sizes [here](https://ant.design/components/layout#breakpoint-width) and [here](https://ant.design/components/menu#menu-demo-inline-collapsed) you can find an oficial example in docs.

Or, if you need a horizontal inline style so perhaps you should use `Buttons` and [`DropDown`](https://ant.design/components/dropdown) and create your own custom menu instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know if useBreakpoints comes at cost of performance because js is involved compared to css media queries?

Comment: I think there is no performance difference between media queries and useBreakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value `{ span: 0 }` to the attribute `labelCol` of the `Form` or the `Form.Input`. See https://ant.design/components/form#formitem for more details